# VBA Code stops after 710 lines without error

Tags: excel, vba, loops

This is my code and it stops after 710 rows. I inserted the Stop after 200 appearances because I know by manually searching after the string that there are only 83 appearances. Nevertheless it finds 201. Can someone explain why the code stops? There are no hidden rows or merged cells and I also set the default to search for all errors... Not only hidden ones.

```
Sub Test_Calcules()
    
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim foundRange As Range
    Dim sumRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim formulaString As String
    Dim numStringsFound As Long
    Dim lastSumRow As Long ' new variable to keep track of the last row where the sum was calculated
    Dim risqueRange As Range ' new variable to hold the range for the Risque PTF formula
    Dim sumFormula As String ' new variable to hold the Sum formula
    Dim sumProductFormula As String ' new variable to hold the Sumproduct formula
    Dim sumValue As Double ' new variable to hold the sum of the Sum formula
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   
    searchString = "Encours" ' change to your specific string
    numStringsFound = 0
    lastSumRow = 0 ' initialize the lastSumRow variable to 0
   
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "I").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column I
        Set foundRange = .Range("I:I").Find(What:=searchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) ' search for the string in column I
        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = foundRange.Address
            Do
                Set foundRange = .Range("I:I").FindNext(foundRange)
            Loop While Not foundRange Is Nothing And foundRange.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
        Do While Not foundRange Is Nothing ' if the string is found, continue
            numStringsFound = numStringsFound + 1
            If numStringsFound > 200 Then
                 Exit Do
            End If
            
            If foundRange.Row > lastSumRow Then ' check if the current row is greater than the last row where the sum was calculated
                Set sumRange = .Range("B" & foundRange.Row + 1, "B" & foundRange.End(xlDown).Row) ' select the range to sum
                sumFormula = "=ROUND(SUM(B" & foundRange.Row + 1 & ":B" & foundRange.End(xlDown).Row & ") ,0)" ' create Sum formula string
                foundRange.Offset(1, 0).formula = sumFormula ' enter formula in the cell below the search string
                sumValue = foundRange.Offset(1, 0).Value ' get the sum value for the Sumproduct formula
                lastSumRow = foundRange.End(xlDown).Row ' update the lastSumRow variable to the last row where the sum was calculated
                Set risqueRange = foundRange.Offset(0, 1).Resize(sumRange.Rows.count, 1) ' set the range for the Risque PTF formula
                sumProductFormula = "=IFERROR((SUMPRODUCT(" & sumRange.Address & "," & sumRange.Offset(0, 4).Address & ")/(" & sumValue & ")),)" ' create Sumproduct formula string
                risqueRange.Offset(1, 0).Cells(1, 1).formula = sumProductFormula ' enter formula in the cell below the Risque PTF string
                lastSumRow = risqueRange.End(xlDown).Row ' update the lastSumRow variable to the last row where the sum was calculated
                Set foundRange = .Range(foundRange.Offset(1, 0), .Cells(lastRow, "I")).Find(What:=searchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) ' find the next occurrence of the search string
            End If
        Loop
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   
    MsgBox "Found " & numStringsFound & " instances of the search string."
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the goal here is, but it seems like you could reduce the number of times you call `.Find` and `.FindNext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Find` with `FindNext` is complex enough that you should consider pushing that out into a separate function.

For example (stripped down to show the basic principle):

```vb
Sub Test_Calcules()
    '...
    '...
    Dim allMatches As Collection, ws As Worksheet
   
    searchString = "Encours" ' change to your specific string
    lastSumRow = 0 ' initialize the lastSumRow variable to 0
   
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set allMatches = FindAll(ws.Range("I:I"), searchString, xlWhole) 'get any matches
    Debug.Print "Found " & allMatches.Count & " matches for '" & searchString & "'"
    
    If allMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each foundRange In allMatches
            If foundRange.Row > lastSumRow Then
                
                'work with each `foundRange`
                
            End If
        Next foundRange
    End If
    '...
    '...
    
End Sub

'Find all matches for `val` in `rng` and return as a Collection of cells
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String, matchType As XlLookAt) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range, addr As String
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=matchType, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()
    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Hi again Tim,
it worked pretty well once haha but now I have the problem that some of the appearances of "Encours" get skipped - altough there is no other formatting/Typos etc. in those cells. There is also no error message - do have a clue why this could be the case? 
I inserted a messagebox telling me how often it finds the strings - and it shows me the correct number.

Comment: There's no way for me to know without your actual data.  Do you mean they're "skipped" because they're not included in the collection returned from `FindAll` ?

Comment: Sorry that was my Bad, I shortly after found out that the ranges Sometimes start/end in the same row so that I Just had to change the > sing to a >=

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out